# Is there a name for this ordering on integer vectors?

Tags: proof-writing, terminology, order-theory

Let $\mathbf{k} \in \mathbb{[n]}^{u}$ be $u$-dimensional arrays, where $[n] = \{0,1,\dots,n\}$. Now let us assume that $\mathbf{k}$ are generated under $u$ nested for loops running from 0 to n. For example if $n=2$, and $u=2$, then the code would print:
$$\langle 0,0\rangle$$
$$\langle 0,1\rangle$$
$$\langle 0,2\rangle$$
$$\langle 0,3\rangle$$
$$\langle 1,0\rangle$$
$$\langle 1,1\rangle$$
$$\langle 1,2\rangle$$

Is there a formal name for this ordering ?

Comment: Alphabetical?  Lexicographic?  Seems like the most common order there is.

Comment: I join team [lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).